# How to achieve Excel-like OLE link behaviour in a custom OLE object

Tags: mfc, ms-word, ole

In Word, you can link to specific cells in an Excel spreadsheet - which can itself exist as a separate file, or as an embedded object in the word doc.
You can then create links to specific cells in that spreadsheet, usually by copying the cells from the in-place activated spreadsheet, and using Paste Special to paste a link to the copied cells.  The link uses excel's !Sheet1!R2C1 format in the link name to identify the cells (and you can edit this name to link to different cells).

How do I go about achieving the same effect for a custom OLE object (built using MFC OLE classes)?
Is it even possible, or does Word use built-in knowledge about Excel to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **Item Moniker**. You need to implement `IOleItemContainer` to do this.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693722(VS.85).aspx

> When combined with a file moniker, an item moniker forms a complete path. Item monikers thus extend the notion of path names beyond the file system, defining path names to identify individual objects, not just files.

The long answer is no, Word does not make use of secret knowledge about Excel (or vice-versa), though I am sure it helps that OLE was built with embedding Excel into Word as a major use-case.

You can also embed an Excel Range in Internet Explorer, or pretty much anything that supports embedding. And you can access a range object and alter its properties from VBScript, by using `Set oRange = GetObject("c:\path\to\spreadsheet.xls!Sheet1!R2C1")` or similar.

Comment: OK, so having created the Item Moniker, how do you 'hand it out', as the doco for CreateItemMoniker says?  Do you register it in the ROT?

Comment: Hi, no ROT is for the main object, not the item within it. For OLE Link behaviour, you need to supply the CF_LINKSOURCE. Usually it gets to the destination from the clipboard via paste special.

Comment: A good starting point for MSDN exploration is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/838a3whf(VS.80).aspx